# How does SQLite sort characters?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

When sorting in SQLite (e.g. ascending or descending) how does SQLite sort characters and special characters (e.g. $, ¥, ?, `, etc.) ? I've tried looking for a table that displays how special characters are treated but have been unable to find anything.

Comment: Good question!, the sort of the characters depends on the Collation but i´d like to see that table too! =0

Comment: @Elenasys - Yep! I was hoping for a "Here's what sorting looks like for X collation" somewhere out there! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting is based on [collation sequence](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html#collation). The default collation sequence is just [`memcmp()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/memcmp.3.html) i.e. byte-by-byte comparison of raw byte values. For ASCII special characters, consult your nearest ASCII table. Sorting of non-ASCII character with `memcmp()` really depends on the character encoding.

Also note that while the sqlite C library supports custom collation sequences, the Android sqlite wrapper doesn't.